# asp:dropdown auto complete with pause in typing

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a standard asp:dropdown control, by default this allows the user to type into it and it will auto select the best matched item form the list. They can also drop the list down.

My user is entering a work order number with a pause like this:

- Type the first 4 characters
- Refer to a document to lookup the next 4 characters (pause in typing)
- Type in next characters

**Example of the asp markup**

```
 <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="uxWorkOrder" Width="386"></asp:DropDownList>
```

**Questions**

1. With the pause in typing the dropdown only filters on the first 4 characters, what's the best approach to allow the user to pause and continue on?
2. How can the user reset the text to blankwithout using the mouse to scroll to the top 'blank item' (Preferably by pressing the spacebar)?

Comment: Is it asp.net or asp-classic?

Comment: asp.net, with c# code behind, not sure why the tag for asp-classic was added I'll remove it.. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your *Question#1*, I don't think you can control that behavior. (I might be wrong though).

**Edit To Include Answer For Question#1:** Because, one can't define how long a pause could be; I assume here that to start a fresh search on combo; one should press the *space* key

```
function checkBlank() {
            if (event.keyCode == 32) {
                document.getElementById('ddlMain').value = '';
                document.getElementById('txtSearchText').value = '';
                return false;
            }

            document.getElementById('txtSearchText').value = document.getElementById('txtSearchText').value + String.fromCharCode(event.which);

            makeSelection();

            return true;
        }

        function makeSelection() {
            var options = document.getElementById('ddlMain').options;
            var matchString = document.getElementById('txtSearchText').value.toLowerCase();
            for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                if (options[i].value.toLowerCase().indexOf(matchString) == 0) {
                    options[i].selected = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlMain" onkeydown="javascript:return checkBlank();">
                <asp:ListItem Text="" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Apple" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Orange" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Banana" />
    </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="txtSearchText" />
```

Simply for `Question#2`, you can use javascript as shown below

```
function checkBlank() {
    if (event.keyCode == 32) {
        document.getElementById('ddlMain').value = '';
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlMain" onkeydown="javascript:return checkBlank();">
            <asp:ListItem Text="" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Apple" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Orange" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Banana" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Thanks for question 2, looks like a simple option. I'm really after a solution for question 1 so will wait on that before allocating answer.

Comment: Actually John, I have a solution for the first one. But what confuses me is _how do you define this pause_. How long CAN that be? Because, you could write code considering the pause. But at some point user would want to have that combo behaving as the usual one (I mean, he might be trying to make a selection in the combo afresh)

Comment: See my **Edit To Include Answer For Question#1:** now.